# Sign out of all devices iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios

I have someone cyber-stalking me who has somehow learned my iCloud password. I've changed it since, but they are still signed in to the "Find My iPhone" app and are able to make noises and alerts and possibly lock or erase my phone. How do I force a sign out of that app? On icloud.com, under the settings menu, I see the option "Sign out of all browsers currently signed in to iCloud.com", however I know from the notification email that they are accessing the phone via the iOS app. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should kick them out of all connections regardless of what they are using to connect.  Most (if not all)  iOS apps that need to use some sort of internet connection for functionality talk to a webserver using various methods of data exchange, but at the end of the day it's http/https and there is a session registered with the server. Delete that session and connection is cut.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I think it did work, I haven't had any issues since changing the password and clicking that link.